# Android app is crashing while playing Youtube player with onResume action

Tags: android, crash, youtube-api, onresume

[image: Crash Report]

App is crashing on resume of Youtube player in device.
Crashing is on android 6.0 and below.
Here is my code for youtube player :

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (youTubePlayer != null) {
        youTubePlayer.release();
        youTubePlayer = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mReceiver != null) {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if (youTubePlayer != null && videoID != null) {
        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoID,currentPlayerTime);
        youTubePlayer.play();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if (youTubePlayer != null) {
        if(youTubePlayer.isPlaying()) {
           currentPlayerTime = youTubePlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis();
            youTubePlayer.pause();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    if (videoID != null) {
        youTubePlayer = player;
        if (youTubePlayer != null && mReceiver != null) {
            player.setOnFullscreenListener(this);

            if (mAutoRotation) {
                player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION
                        | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI
                        | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE
                        | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);
            } else {
                player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION
                        | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI
                        | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);
            }

            if (wasRestored) {
                player.play();
            } else {
                try {
                    player.loadVideo(videoID,0);
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    youTubeView.initialize(YouTubeConstants.youtube_API_key, this);
                }
            }
            mReceiver.player = player;
        }
    }
}
```

Currently found crash on Micromax, samsung, Redmi devices.
The app is specifically crash, when app comes in foreground and calls onResume() method.

Comment: where is your `videoID` variable ? can you post the complete code.

Comment: @sagarsuri : I am getting videoId from previous activity, and just passing here.

Comment: try to print and check the value in the onResume() of the current activity.